# Vertically align items inside an HStack

Tags: swiftui

So I have an `HStack`, but I can't seem to get the items to properly align vertically, so I wanted to reach out and see if the community can help me.

So here is the code:

```
HStack(alignment: .center) {
    Text("Already have an account?")
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Medium", size: 16))
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .lineLimit(1)
    Button(action: {
        // Action
    }) {
        Text("Sign In")
            .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Medium", size: 16))
    }
}
.padding(.bottom, 5)
.opacity(0.9)
.border(.yellow)
```

That produces this:
[image]

As you can see, the text inside the `HStack`, is not vertically aligned, which is driving me nuts and I can't figure it out using modifiers, so I wanted to reach out and see what would be a great way to get things inside an `HStack` or even `VStack` and have them be vertically/horizontally aligned properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **SwiftUI**, the order of the modifiers matter. You're setting a bottom `padding` of 5 then bordering the `View`. If you think about it, the result you're getting is completely logical.

To remedy the issue, move the `padding` modifier after the `border` one:

```
HStack(alignment: .center) {
    Text("Already have an account?")
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Medium", size: 16))
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .lineLimit(1)
    Button(action: {
        // Action
    }) {
        Text("Sign In")
            .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Medium", size: 16))
    }
}
.opacity(0.9)
.border(.yellow)
.padding(.bottom, 5)
```

And remember, order **always** matters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one.

```
   HStack(alignment: .center) {
       Text("Already have an account?")
           .foregroundColor(Color.white)
           .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Medium", size: 20))
           .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
           .lineLimit(1)
       Button(action: {
           //action
       }) {
           Text("Sign In")
               .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Medium", size: 20))
       }
   }
   .opacity(0.9)
   .padding()
   .border(.yellow)
```

[image]